# Como chamar a mesma tarefa mais de 1 vez

Tags: java, eclipse

Tenho a seguinte tarefa:

```
Timer tempovolta1 = new Timer();
TimerTask tarefavolta1 = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        jButton1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }
};
```

Quero-a chamar várias vezes:

```
tempo1.schedule(tarefa1, 2000 );
```

Depois a um tempo maior eu vou chamar ela e dá **ERRO**:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task already scheduled or cancelled

Comment: removi a outra pergunta

Comment: Diogo vejo uma certa resistência sua em relação a construção de perguntas de acordo com o site. Ficar recriando uma pergunta não vai fazer com que você obtenha respostas, se a pergunta não está conforme um padrão pre estabelecido para o site. Pare um tempinho e dê uma lida em [ask] e [help/dont-ask] e depois edite sua pergunta conforme as dicas destes links. E *sempre* que for possível, adicione um [mcve]. Se você seguir as dicas destes links, suas perguntas melhorarão de qualidade e as respostas virão na mesma proporção.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que percebi você deseja ou precisa usar na verdade o timer do Swing.

Defina uma constante por exemplo

```
private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 50;
```

Seu Timer

```
new javax.swing.Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        loopTeste();
     }
  }).start();
```

E seu método

```
public void loopTeste() {
      button.setLocation(button.getLocation().x + 5, button.getLocation().y);
      getContentPane().repaint();
   }
```

Comment: não entendi, pensei que tivesse que usar algo como mult-timer ou cancelar a tarefa depois de executar, funcionaria ?

Comment: @DiogoCipriano o código funcionou?

Comment: eu usei timer para dar um intervalo entra a execução de um for

Comment: preciso chamar o mesmo timer várias vezes

Comment: não sei aonde e como usar o que você escreveu